# How to use config system in Extjs 4 for Extjs 5?

Tags: extjs4, config, extjs5

I have a BaseDBController and  it has a config which parameters are serviceInput,serviceName,className.

```
config: {
        serviceInput:'', 
        serviceName: '', 
        className: ''
    },
```

In Extjs 4 I use the parameters as this.getServiceInput(),this.getServiceName()... in my project.
I want to upgrade my project from Extjs4 to Extjs5, config property doesn't work in Extjs5.

Could you help me how to handle the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be something else wrong as config works as expected in Ext 5